# Django: Order query by AVG() field in related table

Tags: python, django

I have two models

```
class Item(VoteModel, models.Model):
    **some_fields**

class ItemRating(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

I want to order Item query by Averadge score from ItemRating

In SQL, it will something like this

```
SELECT it.*, AVG(ir.score) as rating FROM Item it, ItemRating ir WHERE it.id = ir.item_id ORDER BY rating;
```

How to do it in django ? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it's very simple.

You can annotate you model's query with field from related table, and order or do other operation with it.

Code to my question:

```
item = Item.objects.all()               
itemsrc = item.annotate(rating=Avg('itemrating__score')).order_by('rating')
```

Check documentation for more details.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates

Answer (score 0):

just try this one and check does it meet your requirements :

```
from django.db.models import Avg
frst = Item.objects.value_list('id', flat=True)  
scnd = ItemRating.objects.filter(
      item_id__in=frst).annotate(rating=Avg('score')).order_by('rating').values_list('rating', flat=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. It's close to what i need, but i need fields from Item model, which will not be available for `scnd` variable. Can you update your code ?

Comment: Have you tried your sql query ? Can you post its output ?

Comment: I found how to make so, thank you for your help - your answer lead me to solution!